# VQmod 2.4.1 not working

Tags: vqmod

I tried this thing in a separate new opencart 2.0.1.1 installation it work well there, but not in existing project, I tried uninstalling all extensions and removing all other xml files, changing vqmod to 2.5.1 but no output.

Below is code snippet. file saved as "order_modification_admin.xml"
This is done on localhost.
How could I solve this, Please Help. 
Thanks

```
<modification>
    <id>Order Modification for Admin Area</id>
    <version>2.0.1.1</version>
    <vqmver>2.4.1</vqmver>
    <author>Me</author>
        <!--Email menu header starts-->
        <file name="admin/controller/common/headers.php">
            <operation error="log"> 
                <search position="after"><![CDATA[$data['title']]]></search>
                <add><![CDATA[
                    /**Order modification starts*/                        
                    die('here');    
                    /**Order modification ends*/
                ]]></add>
            </operation>
    </file>
        <!--Config setting Ends-->        
</modification>
```

Answer (score 2):

i have a solution simple 5 step
1.Download LocalCopy.zip

```
- http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=18892
```

2.unzip in install from extenstion installer in admin panel

3.Download Vqmod installer
    http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=22378&filter_search=VQMOD
4.install from extenstion installer
5.Vqmod will be install

Note:in case you get error of ftp than set ftp from store->setting->ftp
and if get error in step 4 than uninstall LocalCopy extenstion and install again extenstion installer

if you still get problem contact me